# Order of operations for multiplying three matrices

Tags: matrices, multiplicative-function

If I have a $1\times 2$ matrix $A$, a $2\times 2$ matrix $B$, and a $2\times 2$ matrix $C$, and am asked to calculate ABC, is there a specific order in which I have to carry out the multiplication?

Would I be correct in assuming I have to calculate $AB$ first to get a $1\times 2$ matrix, and then multiply that result by the $2\times 2$ matrix $C$?

Or can you also calculate $BC$ first and then multiply that result by $A$?

Comment: Do an example with $A=(1,2)$, and some easy $B$, $C$. Then first calculate $A(BC)$ and then $(AB)C$. What do you get?

Answer (score 8):

[Matrix multiplication is associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), so you can do it in whichever order you like.  You can prove it by writing the matrix multiply in summation notation each way and seeing they match.

Answer (score 5):

Matrix multiplication is associative, i.e. $(AB)C=A(BC)$ for every three matrices where multiplication makes sense (i.e. the sizes are right).

For the record, the proof goes something like this: if $A=(A_{ij})_{1\le i \le m, 1\le j \le n}$ ($m\times n$ matrix), $B=(B_{jk})_{1\le j \le n,1\le k \le p}$ ($n\times p$ matrix) and $C=(C_{kl})_{1\le k \le p,1\le l \le q}$ ($p\times q$ matrix), then both $(AB)C$ and $A(BC)$ will be $m\times q$ matrices. For all $1\le i\le m, 1\le l\le q$ we have:

$$((AB)C)_{il}=\sum_{k=1}^{p}(AB)_{ik}C_{kl}=\sum_{k=1}^{p}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}B_{jk}\right)C_{kl}=\sum_{k=1}^{p}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}(A_{ij}B_{jk})C_{kl}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{p}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}(B_{jk}C_{kl})\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{p}A_{ij}(B_{jk}C_{kl})\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{p}B_{jk}C_{kl}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}(BC)_{jl}=(A(BC))_{il}$$

That means that the matrices $(AB)C$ and $A(BC)$ have all their components pairwise equal, thus $(AB)C=A(BC)$.